# React Native How to LazyLoad image

Tags: image, reactjs, react-native, lazy-loading, reactjs-flux

I have a listview where i want to show image on each row and I don't want to show whole 25 images at once. I just wanted to load image which come in viewport.

I am getting url in props

```
<Image source={{uri: this.props.media.image_url}} 
       style={{ width:this.props.media.width,
       height: this.props.media.height}}
/>
```

How can I achieve this in react native.
Note: I have tried these library but none working for me. Probably the version issue that it has written for old version of react Plus some of it does not work with dynamic props

[react-native-lazyload](https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-lazyload)

[react-lazy-load](https://github.com/loktar00/react-lazy-load)

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [react native elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/).

**Add to project**: `npm install --save react-native-elements`

**Usage**:

```
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Image } from 'react-native-elements';

// Standard Image
<Image
  source={{ uri: image }}
  style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
/>


// Image with custom placeholder content
<Image
  source={{ uri: image }}
  style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
  PlaceholderContent={<ActivityIndicator />}
/>
```

Source: [react native elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/image.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin. It is very comprehensive https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-lazyload